# How to use JQuery date control in .NET repeater control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datepicker

I have Repeater Control in which I have jQuery datepicker.
The datepicker pops up when I click on textbox but when I select date it gets populated only on the first textbox in the Repeater control.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="datepicker" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker" ClientIDMode="Static"  Text='<%#Container.DataItem("FOLLOWUP_DATE")%>'></asp:TextBox>
```

JQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside repeater make div with different ids, for example:

```
<asp:repeater id="rptRepeater" runat="server">
   <itemtemplate>
     <div id="datepicker-<%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>"></div>
  </itemtemplate>

</asp:repeater>
```

Then in script initialize datepickers:

```
<script>
  $('#datepicker-1').datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true
 });

$('#datepicker-2').datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true
  });
```

Of course in javasript you should use some kind of loop.